# Wrapping a multi level mapping associated entity by parent entity

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have entities Organisation,Employee,Role

```
@Entity
public class Organization
{
....
@OneToMany
List<Employee> employees;
}

@Entity
public class Employee
{
....
@OneToMany
List<Role> roles;
}

@Entity
public class Role
{
....
String roleName;
}
```

I wish to maintain same structure for all the get results irrelevant of the entity(it can be organisation,employee or role) which will have the required entity fields and all other fields will be null.

Lets say I am having  List of Role. I can acheive my requirement by below code

```
 Employee employee = new Employee();
 employee.setRoles(roles );
 Organization org = new Organization();
 org.setEmployee(employee);
```

.But is there is any way to acheive below structure without above setter and constructor code?

```
{
 ...
  employees:[
    roles:[
          {
          ...
          },
           {
            ....}
           ],
           ....
           ]
 }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please add more detailed description, to be honest I have no ideas what you are asking about

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand `Employee` has `roleId`. If that is the case, you could set `Role role` object instead of `Long roleId` inside of **Employee.class** using `@JoinColumn`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="roleId", referencedColumnName="id")
private Role role;
```

Keep in mind that `name="roleId"` is the filed from the **Employee.class** and `referencedColumnName="id"` is the `id` field from the **Role.class**

Comment: That I have in my code. Here I just missed that in my question. By that I will get the associated objects. I am using `@JsonManagedReference` and  `@JsonBackReference`. So my `organisationRepository.findAll()` will give my output as given json structure. But I want `roleRepository.findAll()` result also wrapped up by Organisation object

Comment: Why don't you create `OrganizationDTO.class` that will have all the information from your `Organization.class`  as well as the `List<Employee> employees `. Your list of employees will be filled from your `employeeRepository`?